# Reset validation messages after close Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I have a modal with my inputs, I'm using [jQuery.Validate](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) to validate my form on submit, my problem is that when I close the modal and then I open the modal again the messages from validation still there, so my question is, how can I reset or hide those messages when I close the modal?

I tried with this but doesn't work

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    window.alertas.reset();
 });
```

How can I solve this?

[Here is a sample](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VKAaAV) code to play with.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use together jQuery and jQuery Validate's `resetForm()`:

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    var $alertas = $('#alertas');
    $alertas.validate().resetForm();
    $alertas.find('.error').removeClass('error');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `reset()`, try using jQuery Validate's `resetForm()`:

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $("#alertas").validate().resetForm();
});
```

Comment: Works fine just a little issue, if you check again my code example link and probe it, works fine but when I try to open again the modal, all the select inputs have color red from .error class

Comment: This helped me fix my issue, however something to note the above is dependant on you having bootstrap.min.js - i searched for 5 hours and then thought wait a minute i don't have this file! Added in as cdn and worked a charm

Answer (score 0):

```
var validator = $("#myModal").validate();
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (){
   validator.resetForm();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you able to find the div which have validation messages then you can try this as well, where uploadModal is Modal popup id and uploadErrorMessages is validation message div id.

```
   $('#uploadModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () 
    {
     $("#uploadErrorMessages").css("display", "none");

    });
```